# JSF validation. can this be simplified?

Tags: jsf

I have a simple form with a bunch of fields. each of them is required, and each has a different name:

- city
- state

when the form is submitted i check if each field is empty and add a **unique message** for each validation to the context like:

- city is required
- state is required

i cant simply use the required=true attribute on the jsp because the message will be generic and this is not what is needed.

I am fairly new to jsf, so please tell me of a better way to do this?

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please don't add tags that do not have a relation to the post. Meta tags like [noob] are not welcome here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Either* use `requiredMessage` attribute

```
<h:inputSomething required="true" requiredMessage="Foo is required" />
```

---

*Or* use `label` attribute and supply a custom required message template.

```
<h:inputSomething label="Foo" required="true" />
```

with a `CustomMessages.properties` in the classpath which contains the custom message template

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = {0} is required.
```

The `{0}` will be substituted with the value of the `label` attribute. You can find an overview of all keys in the JSF specification (e.g. [JSF 2.0 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr252/index2.html) - chapter 2.5.2.4). Declare the message properties file in `faces-config.xml` as `message-bundle`:

```
<application>
    <message-bundle>com.example.CustomMessages</message-bundle>
</application>
```

(assuming that it's in the package `com.example`, you can name it whatever you want)

For more message template keys, check the JSF specification.

Comment: @BalusC Which is the best and simplest way in JSF validation:

1. Built-in validation components
2. Application level validations
3. Custom validation components using Validator interface
4. Validation methods in backing beans

I am really confused!

Comment: Just pick the one requiring least code/configuration.