# JSF form validation easy way to use custom text

Tags: forms, jsp, validation, jsf

I am using this to validate my form `<h:message for="username" showDetail="false" showSummary="true"/>`  with `required="true"` but I get really ugly text because these cryptic ids are shown.

Can I somehow check if any error was throw at all and then just print some basic message hardcoded into the xthml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those "cryptic" IDs are controllable by the `label` attribute.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.user.name}" required="true" label="Username" />
```

You can also use the `requiredMessage` attribute to provide a full custom message.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.user.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter this field" />
```

There exist also the `validatorMessage` and `converterMessage` attributes for the case you'd like to define a common validation or conversion failure message in the view side.

#### See also:

- [JSF validation. can this be simplified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034540/jsf-validation-can-this-be-simplified)
- [JSF 2.0 tutorial - Finetuning validation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#FinetuningValidation)